# How to return global_messages as JSON string?

Tags: template, json, global-messages

I am trying to echo `global_messages` via `JSON` on the frontend.

I have been looking around for some examples of how to return `global_messages` as a `JSON` string but cannot find anything that has helped with my endeavours.

So far I have been able to extend `Mage_Core_Block_Messages` with my own `Company_Core_Block_Messages` class then I have attempted to use `JSON` encode to when returning the `$html` but have been unsuccessful:

```
public function getGroupedHtml()
{
    $types = array(
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::ERROR,
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::WARNING,
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::NOTICE,
        Mage_Core_Model_Message::SUCCESS
    );
    $html = '';
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        if ( $messages = $this->getMessages($type) ) {
            if ( !$html ) {
                $html .= '<' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . ' class="messages">';
            }
            $html .= $this->_renderTextMessages($this->_getTextMessages($messages), $type);
            $html .= $this->_renderPopupMessages($this->_getPopupMessages($messages));
        }
    }
    if ( $html) {
        $html .= '</' . $this->_messagesFirstLevelTagName . '>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Inside my custom_messages.phtml I would like to echo the returned string but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this and would like to ask for some guidance please...

```
<script>
    new Ajax.Updater('<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml(); ?>');
</script>
```

Has anyone done something similar before?